# typeof returns integer for something that is clearly a factor

Tags: r

Create a variable:

```
a_variable <- c("a","b","c")
```

Check type:

```
typeof(a_variable)
```

I want a factor - change to factor:

```
a_variable <- as.factor(a_variable)
```

Check type:

```
typeof(a_variable)
```

Says that it's integer!? As an R newb, this is confusing. I just told R to make a factor not an integer.

Test to see if it somehow magically did create an integer:

```
a_variable * 1
```

Hmm... I get an error message saying `"*" isn't meaningful for factors`. This seems weird to me since R just told me it was an integer!?

Clearly it's me who is confused, can someone more enlightened help make sense of this madness for me?

Comment: Factor variables are stored as integers. Learn to use `class` or `str` rather than `typeof` (or `mode`). They give more useful information.

Comment: @42- I think you should copy your comment as a answer to mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If what you wanted to know was "what class was held by a vector?" then use `class`. If you wanted to test "whether a vector was a factor?" then use `is.factor`.

The value returned by `typeof` being integer for factors is a *language* *feature* that confused me as well in my early days of R programming. The `typeof` function is giving information that's at a "lower" level of abstraction. Factor variables (and also Dates) *are* stored as integers. Datetimes are stored as `numeric`. Learn to use `class` or `str` rather than `typeof` (or `mode`). They give more useful information. You can look at the full "structure" of a factor variable with `dput`:

```
 dput( factor( rep( letters[1:5], 2) ) )
# structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), 
            .Label = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), class = "factor")
```

The character values that are usually thought of as the factor values are actually stored in an **attribute** (which is what "levels" returns), while the "main" part of the variable is a set of integer indices pointing to  various level "attributes"), named `.Label`, so `mode` returns "numeric" and `typeof` returns "integer". For this reason one usually needs to use `as.character` that will coerce to what most people think of as "factors", namely their character representations.

Answer (score 1):

More on **str** - the surprising information for me was it's an abbreviation of "structure" not "string".
It can be clearly seen in the bottommost example how str command is capturing it subjectively clearer than dput, naming it “Factor w/ N levels”:

```
str(head(abalone$Age, 5))
 Factor w/ 3 levels "Mid","Old","Yng": 2 3 1 1 3
```

Thank you for asking this question, as I've found data types in R confusing and ran into the same issue while processing the Abalone dataset from *UCI Machine Learning Repository*.
I've continued on with the research following the reply by [IRTFM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1855677/42).
It eventually helped me understand the typing and hopefully could help someone else. I found this resource helpful on understanding R data types: [R-supp-data-structures](https://swcarpentry.github.io/r-novice-inflammation/13-supp-data-structures/)

What I've observed while processing the data.frame from Abalon dataset:

1. running lapply function on the "Age" column of the data.frame is resulting in a "list" of "character" type objects - due to the lapply property always returning a list even if in this case it could be an atomic vector
2. further applying unlist function on the "Age" column of the data.frame is resulting in an "atomic vector" of "character" type object
3. afer encoding vector as a factor we get a "factor" class object

The code example:

```
#
# Understanding datatypes while processing Abalone dataset  
#
download.file('http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/abalone/abalone.data', 'abalone.data')
abalone  = read.table("abalone.data", header = FALSE, sep=",", na.strings= "*")

# name columns of a data.frame object
colnames(abalone) <- c('Sex', 'Length','Diameter','Height','Whole w.', 'Shucked w.', 'Viscera w.','Shell w.','Rings')
dput(head(abalone, 1))

# discretize numeric rings to three ranges of an abalone age
additiveRingsToAgeConst = 1.5;

abalone$Age = lapply(abalone[,'Rings'] + additiveRingsToAgeConst, function (x) {
  if (x > 11.5)     {"Old"}
  else if (x > 9.5) {"Mid"}
  else              {"Yng"}   
})

# 1. running lapply function on the "Age" column of the data.frame is resulting in a "list" of "character" type objects
dput(head(abalone$Age, 5))
str(head(abalone$Age, 5))
# 2. further applying unlist function on the "Age" column of the data.frame is resulting in an "atomic vector" of "character" type object
abalone$Age = unlist(abalone$Age);
dput(head(abalone$Age, 5))
str(head(abalone$Age, 5))
# 3. afer encoding vector as a factor we get a "factor" class object
abalone$Age = as.factor(abalone$Age)
dput(head(abalone$Age, 5))
str(head(abalone$Age, 5))
```

Code execution results:

```
> # 1. running lapply function on the "Age" column of 
  #    the data.frame is resulting in a "list" of "character" type objects
> dput(head(abalone$Age, 5))
list("Old", "Yng", "Mid", "Mid", "Yng")
> str(head(abalone$Age, 5))
List of 5
 $ : chr "Old"
 $ : chr "Yng"
 $ : chr "Mid"
 $ : chr "Mid"
 $ : chr "Yng"

> # 2. further applying unlist function on the "Age" column of the data.frame 
  #    is resulting in an "atomic vector" of "character" type object
> abalone$Age = unlist(abalone$Age);
> dput(head(abalone$Age, 5))
c("Old", "Yng", "Mid", "Mid", "Yng")
> str(head(abalone$Age, 5))
 chr [1:5] "Old" "Yng" "Mid" "Mid" "Yng"

> # 3. afer encoding vector as a factor we get a "factor" class object
> abalone$Age = as.factor(abalone$Age)
> dput(head(abalone$Age, 5))
structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("Mid", "Old", "Yng"
), class = "factor")
> str(head(abalone$Age, 5))
 Factor w/ 3 levels "Mid","Old","Yng": 2 3 1 1 3
```

Comment: I don't really understand how your post answers the question.  Also for example of course lapply returns a list as is documented, there are other *apply methods that will return a vector if that is what you want. However it would make more sense to use `cut()` to do what you want, specifying that you want an ordered factor as a result.

Comment: Hey Elin! thank you for your reply. I think it connects in the str in the first line and the last in the example: str(head(abalone$Age, 5))
 Factor w/ 3 levels "Mid","Old","Yng": 2 3 1 1 3. Str is clearly reporting Factor type in oposition to typeof. Just hoping to learn something here. If the comment is useless, consider this a newbie’s entry to be voted down. Shemy

Comment: I don't think the OP mentioned str() at all.   If you want to expand on the other answer that's possibly okay or if you want to provide a different explanation that's fine.  But you shouldn't provide irrelevant narrative (such as that lapply returns a list which is what it is documented as doing).