# How to connvert timestamp-like format become a timestamp in R?

Tags: r

I have a dataset as .csv format. This data includes a timestamp-like format:

```
> head(HC_40,n=10)
          obs_id   SiteId  Timestamp       ForecastId           Value
   937757 5338068     40 03/07/2015 14:30       1002  6.997.984.367.355.440
   937758 3210822     40 03/07/2015 15:30       1002 15.518.012.898.186.300
   937759  412101     40 03/07/2015 16:30       1002  6.674.491.990.937.700
   937760 1284142     40 03/07/2015 17:30       1002  4.920.282.615.641.480
   937761 1083737     40 03/07/2015 18:30       1002  4.118.787.012.290.970
   937762 4835789     40 03/07/2015 19:30       1002 17.199.203.354.454.000
   937763 6108559     40 03/07/2015 20:30       1002 11.584.402.269.325.700
   937764 5609878     40 03/07/2015 21:30       1002 14.093.340.266.945.500
   937765 3869294     40 03/07/2015 22:30       1002  6.063.987.507.173.930
   937766 3517578     40 03/07/2015 23:30       1002 80.017.658.455.307.200
```

But, when I checked the type, It was an integer. Is there any explanation for this?

```
> sapply(HC_40,typeof)
    obs_id     SiteId  Timestamp ForecastId      Value 
   "integer"  "integer"  "integer"  "integer"  "integer"
```

What should I do to convert this format become timestamp?

what I have tried and failed:

```
first--->dataTime<-as.Date.POSIXct(HC_40$Timestamp,format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
second-->HC_40$Timestamp = as.Date(strptime(as.character(HC_40$Timestamp), "%d/%m/%Y/ %H:%M"))
```

It doesn't work actually, my data become

```
> HC_40$Timestamp<-as.POSIXct(HC_40$Timestamp,format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
> head(HC_40,n=10)
        obs_id SiteId           Timestamp ForecastId                  Value
937757 5338068     40 1970-01-01 07:00:00       1002  6.997.984.367.355.440
937758 3210822     40 1970-01-01 07:00:00       1002 15.518.012.898.186.300
937759  412101     40 1970-01-01 07:00:00       1002  6.674.491.990.937.700
937760 1284142     40 1970-01-01 07:00:00       1002  4.920.282.615.641.480
937761 1083737     40 1970-01-01 07:00:00       1002  4.118.787.012.290.970
937762 4835789     40 1970-01-01 07:00:00       1002 17.199.203.354.454.000
937763 6108559     40 1970-01-01 07:00:00       1002 11.584.402.269.325.700
937764 5609878     40 1970-01-01 07:00:00       1002 14.093.340.266.945.500
937765 3869294     40 1970-01-01 07:00:00       1002  6.063.987.507.173.930
937766 3517578     40 1970-01-01 07:00:00       1002 80.017.658.455.307.200
```

Comment: Your data entry process probably imported those as factor variables which are integer type variables.

Comment: Please see below comments to @LachlanO's answer; also, you've got an erroneous `"/"` in your `second` command: It should be `HC_40$Timestamp <- strptime(as.character(HC_40$Timestamp), format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data entry process probably imported those as factor variables which are integer type variables. This also illustrates why nusing `typeof` is a bad method for investigating the structure of R objects. Use instead either `str` or `class`.

So , probably:

```
HC_40$Timestamp <- as.POSIXct(as.character(HC_40$Timestamp), # convert from factor
                              format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
```

Unfortunately, that format of storing date-times with the year value at the end of the date doesn't lend itself to using colClasses with one of the read.* functions. They need to be read in as character or factors and converted with `as.POSIXct` or `strptime`.

Comment: The conversion `as.character` is actually not necessary; internally `as.POSIXct` calls `as.POSIXlt`, which has a method for `factor`s, which in turn does the `as.character` conversion (see `getAnywhere(as.POSIXlt.factor)`).

Comment: @chinsoon12 `HC_40$Timestamp` is *not* in fact an integer, it's a `factor`! I suggest reversing your edit; simple check: `typeof(factor("a"))` will return `integer` even though it is a `factor`. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35689019/confused-about-types-in-r-typeof-returns-integer-for-something-that-is-clearly) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

The solution should be as simple as

```
HC_40$Timestamp <- as.POSIXct(HC_40$Timestamp, format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
```

Comment: @CaesarAlpha I cannot reproduce your issue. If I use your sample data, both @LachlanO's and @42-'s solutions work. Note that it is `as.POSIXct(...)`, *not* `as.Date.POSIXct(...)`. It works both with `HC_40$Timestamp` as a `factor` and as a `character` vector (no explicit `as.character` is necessary).

Comment: @MauritsEvers, I thought the same as you. Do really old versions of as.POSIXct not have this functionality, or something odd like that?

Comment: @LachlanO Yes, it's strange; also `strptime(as.character(HC_40$Timestamp), format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")` works just fine on my side as well.

Comment: @LachlanO I have tried your suggestion, however all of my data change become 1970-01-01. This is what I mean. :)

Comment: @CaesarAlpha Can you please edit your post to include relevant parts from `sessionInfo()`?

Comment: Thank all, I just try by correcting my code as suggested by @42 (I remove unnecessary '/')