# Inner_Join function failing, colClass not reconciling / Incompatible types

Tags: r, inner-join, geospatial, shapefile, choropleth

I'm trying to create a choropleth map using a .shp shapefile and a csv. I'm stuck on the `inner_join` step and keep receiving the error below, even after using `colClass` function to change the variable type to match my shapefile data. Anyone know what the issue may be?

```
ods_total<-read.csv("ods.csv",stringsAsFactors = FALSE,colClasses = c("STATE_FIPS"="integer"))

> typeof(ods_total$STATE_FIPS)
[1] "integer"

> typeof(map$STATE_FIPS)
[1] "integer"

> map_data<-inner_join(map,ods_total)

Joining, by = c("STATE_NAME", "DRAWSEQ", "STATE_FIPS")
**Error: Can't join on 'STATE_FIPS' x 'STATE_FIPS' because of incompatible types (factor / integer)**"
```

Comment: `map$STATE_FIPS` is a factor.  Compare `class(map$STATE_FIPS)` to `typeof(map$STATE_FIPS)`.  Factors are stored internally as a vector of integers.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35689019/confused-about-types-in-r-typeof-returns-integer-for-something-that-is-clearly).